# Cannot read xport file into python with xport

Tags: python-3.x

I'm attempting to read a large .xpt file into python. I have tried using the xport library, but get the following error

```
with open('C:/Users/matth/OneDrive/Documents/Data Science/TrCount/LLCP2019.XPT', 'rb') as f:
    library = xport.v56.load(f)
```

ValueError: Field names cannot start with an underscore: '_STATE'

It turns out many field names start with an underscore. Obvious (to me) solutions such as replacing the underscores with spaces, blanks, or a random letter only present a different error

```
--> 793             raise ValueError('Neither zero nor NaN: %r' % ibm)
    794 
    795     # IBM-format exponent is base 16, so the mantissa can have up to 3

ValueError: Neither zero nor NaN: b'(\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
```

I'm not sure why this is happening. The file itself is huge. The original file is [here](https://www.cdc.gov/brfss/annual_data/2019/files/LLCP2019XPT.zip)

Answer (score 0):

I tried a bunch of different packages and libraries in python and R and finally got the haven package in R to work.